# Order of widgets in Netbeans JavaFX designer

Tags: netbeans, javafx

I'm using the JavaFX designer in NetBeans for the first time, and I'm not sure how to control the order of my objects layering. I wanted to put an ImageView behind a group of buttons, but it always appears above them. How do I tell the designer that it goes below the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Darn, I knew this would happen. Spend an hour searching, post a question, find the answer five minutes later. The Navigator panel in the bottom left. Just click and drag the item up or down to control ordering.